# Running syncdb on Django project not working: Can't create/write to file 

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I run:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

I get the following output:

```
Creating table auth_permission
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 78, in handle_noargs
cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 84, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (1, "Can't create/write to file '/usr/local/mysql/data/wzhere/auth_permission.MYI' (Errcode: 2)")
```

Any ideas on how to debug?  I've given the database user all the permissions it should need.  Not sure what MySQL is balking at here.

**UPDATE:**  The problem here ended up being that I had installed MySQL multiple times (first 32-bit, then 64-bit when I realized I should be doing that) and although I followed some instructions on how to un-install MySQL, the instructions are slightly different for Snow Leopard.  Once I actually did an uninstall and clean install, this problem went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was how to debug the problem and as already pointed out by Agos, Errno 2 is 'No such file or directory'. You might want to look in the data directory of MySQL and check if the directory is actually there and has correct permissions

```
shell> cd /usr/local/mysql/data/
shell> ls -ld *
drwx------    17 geert   admin         578 Oct  1 19:33 someabstract
```

The above should give you list of directories (which are the MySQL databases) and their permissions. Check whether the 'wzhere' directory in particular..
It's a bit weird error message you get I should say.

(Trying another Django DB back-end wouldn't solve anything in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

> agos@server:~$ perror 2
>   OS error code 2:  No such file or directory

Is your MySQL configured correctly? Try querying it yourself via `mysql` command.
Also, as luc suggested in the comment, try with sqlite.